# Show the validation error template on a different control in WPF

Tags: wpf, validation, templates

I have a `UserControl` that contains other controls and a `TextBox`. It has a `Value` property that is bound to the `TextBox` text and has `ValidatesOnDataErrors` set to True.

When a validation error occurs in the `Value` property binding, the error template (standard red border) is shown around the entire `UserControl`.

Is there a way to show it around the `TextBox` only? 
I'd like to be able to use any error template so simply putting border around textbox and binding its color or something to `Validation.HasError` is not an option.

Here's my code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TextFieldDataTemplate">
    <c:TextField DisplayName="{Binding Name}" Value="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
</DataTemplate>

<controls:FieldBase x:Name="root">
<DockPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=root}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtBox"                 
             Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
             IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

UserControl (FieldBase) is than bound to ModelView which performs validation.

Answer (score 2):

to accomplish this task I've used this solution. It uses converter, that "hides" border by converting (Validation.Errors).CurrentItem to Thickness.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <data:ValidationBorderConverter
            x:Key="ValidationBorderConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Border
        BorderBrush="#ff0000"
        BorderThickness="{Binding 
            ElementName=myControl, 
            Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem, 
            onverter={StaticResource ValidationBorderConverter}}">
        <TextBox
            ToolTip="{Binding 
                ElementName=myControl, 
                Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

ValidationBorderConverter class is pretty simple:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(ValidationError))]
public sealed class ValidationBorderConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value == null) ? new Thickness(0) : new Thickness(1);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```